# "Module object has no attribute" custom class python

Tags: python, nested

Here is my mydatatype.py

```
class answer(object):
    answer_start = 0
    text = ""
    def set(self,answer_start,text):
        self.answer_start = answer_start
        self.text = text



class quas(object):
    question = ""
    answers = answer()
    def set(self,question,answers):
        self.question = question
        self.answers = answers

class textandquas(object):
    context = ""
    qas = quas()
    def set(self,context,qas):
        self.context = context
        self.qas = quas()

class paragraph(object):
    content = []
```

Here is my console code:

```
import mydatatype as mdt
a = mdt.quas()
```

And the error happens. It happens with `quas()` and `textandquas()`, `answer()` and `paragraph()` are not affected. I believe this is some error related to python class-in-class. 
Are there any way that I can put a class in another class like that without nesting the class declaration ?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Please post the full traceback in your question. If there's a `mydatatype.pyc` file (note the c at the end) delete it. Also, are you using iPython in some way (Spyder/Enthought Canopy for example)?

Comment: Also, your recent edit is pretty substantial. Is this new code representative of what's throwing the error?

Comment: Thank you for replying.
The code edit is because the previous one is the wrong version.
I'm using Spyder to run the code.
Using answer() and paragraph() is okay. But using quas() gives error:
a = mdt.quas()

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-619-c5acadbd7098>", line 1, in <module>
    a = mdt.quas()

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'quas'`

Comment: Hold ctrl and press `.`. When it asks, click yes to restarting the kernal. Then try running your code.

Comment: I can't believe it! Turning it off and on actually works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: But there's a problem. I need to turn spyder off and on every time i change mydatatype.py for it to take effect (i.e, whenever i add another datatype). Are there any solution for this ? Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know exactly how namespace works in Spyder, and it seems slightly different to Canopy, but basically if you make changes to an imported module then you won't always see the changed code. In the case of Spyder, the interactive console also seems to be able to affect code.

Comment: In many cases when I run something through Spyder it will give a printout that it's reloading modules. There will be a setting somewhere to reload all imported modules every time you run a script. In your case it will have cached a module and be using old code.